# Show posts randomly in hompage that will be change in every 24 hours

Tags: wordpress

I have over 200 public blog posts and I want 1 of them to randomly to show up each day for 24 hours. Then the next day it will be the another random post, and another random post, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the follows query to get all the posts modified in last 24 hours randomly -

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'after'  => '24 hours ago',
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: You didn't understand,, I want to show 1 post in homepage, this post will be there for 24 hours, and the next hours there will be another post,

Comment: Then just replace 'posts_per_page' => -1, with 'posts_per_page' => 1, to get only 1 post.